# x cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables, int, pixel

I've ran into a few problems with my code. I'll highlight the errors in bold (asterisks **)  :) Thanks in advance 
(code highlighted has this error: x cannot be resolved to a variable")

```
package com.cmnatic.reborn.gui;

public class Bitmap {
    public final int width;
    public final int height;
    public final int[] pixels;

    public Bitmap(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height];
    }

    public void draw(Bitmap bitmap, int xOffs, int yOffs)  {
        for (int y = 0; y<bitmap.height; y++) {
            int yPix = y+yOffs;
            if (yPix<0 || yPix>=height) continue;

            for(int xPix = 0; **x**<bitmap.width; x++) {
                int **xPix** = **x+x0ffs**;
                if (xPix<0 || xPix>=width) continue;

                pixels[xPix+yPix*width] = bitmap.pixels[x + y * bitmap.width];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I've got an odd problem which I'm not sure about:
(code below highlighted has the following error: "Duplicate local variable xPix"

```
for(int xPix = 0; **x**<bitmap.width; x++) {
    int **xPix** = **x+x0ffs**;
    if (xPix<0 || xPix>=width) continue;
```

Thanks in advance,
CMNatic

Comment: xPix and x are two different variables.

Comment: The immediate reaction to this message should be: "Why? I have defined it, wait, ... hmmm where is that sh.. OHHH MY GOOOD, SILLY ME". It is way faster than to ask it on SO.

Answer (score 1):

`xPix` is already defined within the scope of the inner `for` loop. `x` needs to be declared before it can be used so it makes sense to use

```
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++) {
```

Also

```
int xPix = x + x0ffs; // typo
```

should be

```
int xPix = x + xOffs;
```

As always the error messages provide a meaningful indicator as to the nature of the issues...

Comment: Actually he mentioned this --*I'll highlight the errors in bold (asterisks **) :)*

Answer (score 0):

`x` is no where declared but being used in the loop, So the error.
Correct your loop variable to x

```
for(int x = 0; x<bitmap.width; x++) {
        int xPix = x+x0ffs;
        if (xPix<0 || xPix>=width) continue;
```

All the problems will be solved.